# Replace a sky in photos

Tags: image, image-processing, keras, neural-network

I need to process a lot of photos, namely, replace sky to solid color. I thin best solution of my problem is neural networks, so I need to get answer on two my question: what neural networks can process images, does Keras do this? And what other ways exists?

Comment: Your question is too broad, please narrow it down and do your own research beforehand and present such effort in the question

Answer (score 0):

`keras` is a network framework, but not a specific network solution for a task. I think you should look into semantic segmentation networks, which often have pixel-level classification for multiple classes, and those contains the `sky` class with pretrained weights should fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this:

> I need to process a lot of photos, namely, replace sky to solid color.

The rest *"what neural networks can process images, does Keras do this? And what other ways exists?"* is just the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Without knowing in detail how your sample images look like, I would think something like *Neural Networks* is a bit of an overkill in this situation. I would approach the problem like this.

1. I would use the [Hough-Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to detect the *largest* horizontal line in the image. This line would most likely represent the horizon.
2. Everything above this horizon, should be your *sky*. 
   More on a similar image processing algorithm [here](http://au.tono.my/log/20130722-horizon-detection.html).

Of course, without knowing more about the problem at hand, it is difficult to say, what could be the best approach for this problem. You could also try posting your problem on [dsp stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com), with some sample images.